# Can an optout link be included in a scheduled reminder?

Tags: scheduled-reminders

We have started collecting "prospective members" from callers to our 24/7 helpline.  Email addresses are collected via a webform and at the same time a civicrm activity is created.  We have set up one scheduled reminder to go out 24 hours after that activity is created and a second to go out 29 days after the activity created date.

We want to give these prospective members the ability to optout from all communications with us from either email.

It appears that {action.optOutUrl} does not work for scheduled reminders.  Is that correct and if so, can anyone suggest a way to let these prospective members opt out?

We are using CiviCRM 4.4.19 on Drupal 7.

Comment: Have you tried  {action.optOut} or {action.unsubscribe}?

Answer (score 1):

Provide them with a link back to a webform with checksum plus activity id if necessary so the existing Activity is loaded, and set the webform submission to change the status of the Activity to something that is excluded in the Scheduled Reminder.

(NB I am trying to get some unanswered questions answered as that is currently the 'weakest' aspect of our Beta civicrm stackexchange according to these [stats][1])